# qemu-img: error while reading sector 327680: Invalid argument

Tags: qemu, disk-image, vmdk

I am trying to convert vmdk image to raw format but I am getting an error statement.

`qemu-img convert -f vmdk Ubuntu-12.04-LTS-Jeos-1.0-disk1.vmdk -O raw myImage.raw`

and I am getting following error.

`qemu-img: error while reading sector 327680: Invalid argument`

However it creates `myImage.raw` image with 0 disk size. I have googled it but couldn't find any solution.
I am using qemu-img version 1.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. Any suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax needs adjusting. Flag arguments need to come first, then the input file and then the output file.

```
qemu-img convert -f vmdk -O raw Ubuntu-12.04-LTS-Jeos-1.0-disk1.vmdk myImage.raw
```

---

If you're still getting that, it might suggest a corrupted VMDK. I just [downloaded the appliance VMDK](http://ftp2.pl.freebsd.org/pub/VM/VMware/Appliances/ub1204lts-jeos/) and ran:

```
$ qemu-img convert -f vmdk -O raw Ubuntu-12.04-LTS-Jeos-1.0-disk1.vmdk myImage.raw
$ ls -l myImage.raw 
-rw-r--r-- 1 oli oli 2147483648 Jan 16 13:35 myImage.raw
```

That seems to work fine.

**Edit:** This seems like it might be [a side-effect of an old version of qemu](https://serverfault.com/questions/429478/conversion-of-a-vmdk-image-with-qemu-img-failed-with-error-while-reading-sector). I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 with version 1.5.0 of `qemu-utils`. Either upgrade the version of qemu (per the question I linked to) or upgrade Ubuntu.

Comment: I am getting same error.

Comment: Edited. Seems to be a bug in the version of qemu that 12.04 bundles. It works fine in later versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: I upgraded qemu-img to 1.2.0 and it solved the problem. Thanks for help